# CORS Angular 8 it gives me

Tags: java, angular, http-headers, servlet-filters, angular8

I have a CORS problem in my project. From Angular 8 I do:

```
 httpOptions = { 
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Authorization':'Basic bm92Z*********************'
      })
    };
```

and I do get operation in this way:

```
public getStudents() : Observable<IStudent[]>{
  return this.http.get<IStudent[]>(this.writeUrl, this.httpOptions)...// this.writeUrl is the request  url
}
```

In my server with java I do:

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {

    responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
    responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");

    }
```

it gives me CORS and I don't know why, anyone can help me?

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting? Add that to your post. Plus, read the error message. Chances are, the message tells you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Angular server runs on http://localhost:4200/ and spring boot server runs on http://localhost:8080/.

configure a proxy.conf.json parallely to package.json. proxy.conf.json should have

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

configure the same in package.json

```
"scripts" :{"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"}
```

This configuration should proxy your angular calls to spring boot server. Let me know if this works for you, if you still face any issue, post that error. we could check from there.