# blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Error in Angular 8 application with Solr 8.1.0

Tags: angular, solr, cors

I am getting a CORS error in my Angular 8 application when i check in the console of Chrome browser.

This is happening when i'm hitting for Solr search version 8.1.0.

This is my solr URL http://abc123.aaa.bbb.com:8983/solr/VW_POB_SOLR_SEARCH_MASTER/select?q=search_text:%22maha%22

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://abc123.aaa.bbb.com:8983/solr/VW_POB_SOLR_SEARCH_MASTER/select?q=search_text:%22maha%22' from origin 'http://localhost:4201' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED`

`core.js:6014 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://abc123.aaa.bbb.com.com:8983/solr/VW_POB_SOLR_SEARCH_MASTER/select?q=search_text:"maha"", ok: false, …}`

I tried out few method's mentioned in the stackoverflow but it doesn't seem's to be working.

[CORS Angular 8 it gives me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559787/cors-angular-8-it-gives-me)

[Having issue with CORS error in angular 8 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009914/having-issue-with-cors-error-in-angular-8-app)

[origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy in Angular7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328474/origin-http-localhost4200-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-in-angular7)

https://www.techiediaries.com/fix-cors-with-angular-cli-proxy-configuration/

I think there is some problem with the Cross Origin I even tried installing CORS through "`npm install --save cors`".

My Proxy.conf.js looks like this:

```
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  }
```

and my angular.json looks like this

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "JBPWebNg": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/JBPWebNg",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/custom-theme.scss",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "JBPWebNg:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "JBPWebNg:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "JBPWebNg:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "JBPWebNg:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "JBPWebNg:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "JWebNg"
}
```

Please let me know if any one know's the fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. The server you are making the request to has to implement CORS to grant JavaScript from your website access. Your JavaScript can't grant itself permission to access another website.

Use a CORS extension from web store of chrome browser.

Here is the link of the extensions: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf/related?hl=en

Comment: In case if my server based application was written in MVC .net i could have installed CORS on that to make it to work. But how to do that in SOLR? And then again the question rises how does it work in other native javascript/jquery application?

Comment: Yes thanks you are correct I just thought of enabling CORS in SOLR and this link worked. http://laurenthinoul.com/how-to-enable-cors-in-solr/

Comment: That extensions solved my issue! Thank you